# Joining a domain with several windows server 2008 instances running on virtual box

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, virtualbox, domain-controller

I'm trying to teach myself Active Directory using the self-paced training kit 70-640 unfortunately my networking and System Administration skills are quite poor and I'm having trouble with Chapter 1 / Lesson 2 / Exercise 2 !

I created 1 virtual machine in Virtual Box "SERVER01", this is the Windows Server 2008R2 domain controller for the contoso.com domain

I created a 2nd virtual machine,"SERVER02", which is Windows Server 2008R2 core. However when I try to join the domain using

```
netdom join %computername% /domain:contoso.com
```

it says "the specified domain does not exist or cannot be contacted".

Both virtual machines have a single network adapter attached to a internal network.

For what it's worth I can ping the Server01 from Server02.

```
SERVER01
IP: 10.0.0.11
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 10.0.0.1
DNS Servers: ::1
DNS Servers: 127.0.0.1

SERVER02
IP: 10.0.0.12
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 10.0.0.1
DNS Servers: fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1 (confused about this!?)
DNS Servers: fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
DNS Servers: fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
```

Also in the network settings of virtual box, what is the significance of promiscuous mode?

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computers joining domain should have first dns server as server01 (10.0.0.11) otherwise they cannot determine DC for a domain.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected it might be something to do with the DNS.

Comment: This is partially incorrect.  Computers joining a domain OR IN A DOMAIN should ONLY HAVE AD DNS Servers listed - NO OTHER DNS SERVER SHOULD BE SPECIFIED - doing so can cause sporadic login delays and problems finding network resources.  Add ISP/other DNS servers as Forwards if you like in the Windows DNS server, but that shouldn't be necessary as Windows can handle all DNS tasks needed.